# PL/pgSQL tracing/execution plan

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Please advice regarding PL/pgSQL "tracing". I would like to write code inside PL/pgSQL procedure that will generate plans and run times for all statements inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some hooks provided by PostgreSQL. Interesting hooks can be plpgsql debug hooks (used by [plpgsql_lint](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_lint) or [plpgsql debugger](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/edb-debugger/)), or executor hooks (used by [autoexplain](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/auto_explain))

Comment: That's fine to enable execution plan on instance level or from client, not for me. I am looking for some solution that will do it from my function code:1. I would like to change some value in my configuration table. 2.My function always read this value, on every execution. Once flag is on: produce execution plan and run time statistics will be generated.

Comment: It is hard, but it is possible. A few years ago, I wrote a small procedures, that modified a all procedures on server - it was used for tracing only http://postgres.cz/wiki/Injekt%C3%A1%C5%BE_zdrojov%C3%A9ho_k%C3%B3du_PL/pgSQL_funkc%C3%AD_za_%C3%BA%C4%8Delem_z%C3%ADsk%C3%A1n%C3%AD_seznamu_pou%C5%BE%C3%ADvan%C3%BDch_funkc%C3%AD but in modern postgresql you can use a function tracing - see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-FUNCTIONS

Comment: I am really sorry, I probably missing something: it's once again server side parameters. I am looking for something that can trigger execution plan generation on session level only, in this case: from PL/pgSQL code. Please point me exactly on code that has to be written.

Comment: you can enable auto_explain for session

Comment: That's was my question: how to do it for session only?

Comment: @YuriLevinsky - you can load a extension manually via statement LOAD - just execute command "LOAD auto_explain"; SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0; auto_explain.log_nested_statements = true;